best approach for training a model to determine patent prior art
I am looking to train a model that will take in text for a patent and be able to output the ids of patents that are most likely to be prior art for that idea. There is a ton of training data for this because every patent has to cite prior art, but I am looking for advice on what type of model I would use to do this since there are so many (100 million+) patents that a patent could potentially reference as prior art. How can the model be able to efficiently determine which patents are most relevant? I was considering training a custom embeddings model but am not sure how to go about this.
